# reloading mvc index view with paraments are not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my index view, the initial load is fine.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DateTime? display_dt)
```

In the actual index view page (index.cshtml) I have some java script to modify the display_dt then it calls the index function in the controller with the parameter using ajax as per below

```
   $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/Reports/Index/',
            data: {
                display_dt: newDate.toJSON()
            }
        })
```

When I trace the code the parameters are passed properly and the output of the index function in the controller is modified as per the input parameter i.e. p_events below is modified depending on the input parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DateTime? display_dt)
....return View(p_events);
```

However in the `index.cshtml`, it does not seem to get updated. The page just display the initial data of events when it was first loaded and does not display the updated list of events.

Is there a function to update the html?I've tried location.reload() but this just reloads the initial data. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: using ajax call, you can not update your view. so to update `html` of your view, first you need to return `view as a partial view` from `controller` then in `ajax response` you will get html. this html you can use as an updated html and bind it in view.

Comment: @vishal, can you please provide an example? I'm new to mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can use location.reload() in the JavaScript success callback.